# AutoMapper 12.0.1 unit test failing for FindTypeMapFor method

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

We are updating Auto mapper from 10.1.1 to 12.0.1 in .netcore. After updating we got error for FindTypeMapFor. So I have added using AutoMapper.Internal; namespace. so that issue is resolved but in unit test file it is getting failed and it is showing "Unsupported expression: ... => ....Internal()
Extension methods (here: InternalApi.Internal) may not be used in setup / verification expressions
"

Below is the code

```
private IMapper _mapper;

    public UtilityService(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

 public string ToSearchAllQuery<T1, T2>(T2 dtoModel, SearchFilterModel filterModel) 
        where T1 : class
        where T2 : class
    {
        var props = typeof(T1).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(SearchAllAttribute)));
        var map = _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.Internal().FindTypeMapFor<T1, T2>();
    }
```

Below is the unit testing code.

```
 private Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
    private Mock<IMapper> _mapper;
    private UtilityService _utilityService;

    [SetUp]
    public void UtilityServiceTestsSetUp()
    {
        _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        _utilityService = new UtilityService(_mapper.Object);
    }

      [SetUp]
        public void SearchAllSetup()
        {
            var locMappingProfile = new ChaseReportLocationMappingProfile();
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(locMappingProfile));
            var mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
            var map = mapper.ConfigurationProvider.Internal().FindTypeMapFor<ChaseReportLocationModel, ChaseReportLocationDTO>();
            ***_mapper.Setup(x => x.ConfigurationProvider.Internal().FindTypeMapFor<ChaseReportLocationModel, ChaseReportLocationDTO>()).Returns(map);***
        }
```

Comment: Why are you mocking `IMapper` just test it with your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Internal()` is internal for a reason. First of all it is an extension method so can't be mocked. From pure technical perspective you can dive into the internals and mimic the internal workings of AutoMapper:

```
var locMappingProfile = new ChaseReportLocationMappingProfile();
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(locMappingProfile));
var mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
var map = mapper.ConfigurationProvider.Internal().FindTypeMapFor<ChaseReportLocationModel, ChaseReportLocationDTO>();

// mock the IConfigurationProvider and the fact that actual implementation
// actually is also IGlobalConfiguration:
var cfgMock = new Mock<IConfigurationProvider>();
var globalCfg = cfgMock.As<IGlobalConfiguration>();
globalCfg.Setup(c => c.FindTypeMapFor<ChaseReportLocationModel, ChaseReportLocationDTO>()).Returns(map);
// setup the mock for provider
_mapper.Setup(x => x.ConfigurationProvider).Returns(globalCfg.Object);
```

But actually you should not do that, just load all the needed profiles and use the actual mapper. I.e. something like:

```
private IMapper _mapper;

[SetUp]
public void UtilityServiceTestsSetUp()
{
    var locMappingProfile = new ChaseReportLocationMappingProfile();
    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(locMappingProfile)); // load all needed profiles.
    _mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you.

Comment: @sadasiva You should mark the answer as accepted, assuming you've already upvoted it.